# Как получить сущность не из Persistence context?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

`Java 17`, `Spring Boot 2.7.8`, `Hibernate`.

Каким образом я могу заставить `Hibernate` отдать сущность не из Persistence context, то есть заставить его не использовать кэш первого уровня в запросе?

Я знаю, что можно использовать `em.detach(T entity)`, а есть другой вариант, т.е. не очищая контекст получить искомую сущность в её актуальном виде из БД?

Comment: Вы можете использовать метод EntityManager.refresh(T entity). Этот метод обновляет состояние сущности в базе данных с текущими данными из БД. Это практически аналогично методу em.detach(T entity), только не освобождает сущность из персистентного контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Кэш первого уровня включен по-умолчанию и его нельзя отключить. При закрытии сессии кэш сессии очищается. Для сессии есть методы `evict()`, `clear()`, `contains()` для работы с кэшем.
Для отключения кэша второго уровня проперти `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false`